# How can I display current date in multiple texts in same page HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, date

**Hello,**
I'm trying to build a keep notes and adding a button that when u touch it adds the corrent date, BUT if i add several buttons the script will not work just will show the first one and i want that show multiple dates when i call that id.

```js
// Date object
var today = new Date();

// Current Date
  var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1);

  document.getElementById("current_date").innerHTML = date;
```

```html
<p id=current_date></p>
<p id=current_date></p>
<p id=current_date></p>
<p id=current_date></p>
```

Comment: `id` attribute in each HTML element should be unique

Comment: @NekoMi  i know i need a solution for thar on script i saw  something interensting  in another post that was : var datestring  = new Date().toLocaleDateString();


// initialize Date to any element input with class="inDate"
document.querySelectorAll('input.inDate')
        .forEach( item => item.value = datestring )   
<input type="text" id="date1" class="inDate" ><br>
<input type="text" id="date2" class="inDate" ><br>
<input type="text" id="date3" class="inDate" ><br>
<input type="text" id="date4" class="inDate" ><br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you can only have one instance of an ID per page, otherwise a lot of things will break including javascript. Secondly, you should use quotes around attribute values (such as `class` and `id`). Here is a working version of what you posted:

```js
// Date object
var today = new Date()

// Current Date
var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)

// querySelectorAll selects elements of the page with a selector, similar to how CSS works
// I used forEach on the list of elements returned by querySelectorAll to change the text content
// of each element with the date you created
document.querySelectorAll(".current_date").forEach((dateElement) => dateElement.innerHTML = date)
```

```html
<p class="current_date"></p>
<p class="current_date"></p>
<p class="current_date"></p>
<p class="current_date"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` is returning only one element. Also, you shouldn't use the same id more times than one.

You can use class instead:

```
<p class="current_date"></p>
<p class="current_date"></p>
```

Then, you can do someting like this

```
// Date object
var today = new Date();

// Current Date
var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1);

// get all of the elements that have current_date class
// note: we are using querySelectorAll() function there
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".current_date");

// then you can use forEach loop
elements.forEach(element => {
    // inner html to the element
    element.innerHTML = date;
});
```